# Sardony sarcasm, irony, satire, or what

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, word-usage, idiom-requests

What is the literary term or convention that best describes the following sentence:

"Socrates drank hemlock, therefore you should drink hemlock"

The term I seek is similar in form to sardony/sarcasm/irony, or perhaps a subset thereof.

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: If this is a [tag:single-word-requests], you should also include an example sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: That sentence *might* be ironic or sarcastic depending on the speaker's intent. @roger-sinasohn is correct, the sentence is fallacious. However, if the speaker knows this and is saying it to make a point, then it could be considered ironic.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a ***[logical fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy)***, specifically an ***[appeal to authority](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority)***.

The excellent site [Your Logical Fallacy Is](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/) describes a fallacy as:

> A logical fallacy is a flaw in reasoning. Logical fallacies are like tricks or illusions of thought, and they're often very sneakily used by politicians and the media to fool people.

and describes the [appeal to authority](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority) as:

> You said that because an authority thinks something, it must therefore be true.

In this case, it's not so much what Socrates said as what he did.  This is often rebutted (by parents) as:

> if your friends jumped off a bridge/cliff/building, would you?

in response to the claim that *All my friends do X so why can't I?*

Comment: Yes, the appeal to authority is a well-known logical fallacy, but to my mind, OP's sentence is *lampooning* this sort of thing. I imagine it might be a comeback to (for instance) someone defending his weird diet fad by saying "Einstein ate like this, you know." (that would be a simple appeal to authority, in itself flawed, as you've pointed out), to which "Socrates drank hemlock, you know." would be a snarky comeback. So I think you've missed the point of the OP's question a little.

Comment: I agree with logical fallacy, but he was condemned to drink poison. I just find it find weird to describe that as an appeal to authority. Maybe if he was like Mithridates, who I guess took poison voluntarily.

Answer (score -1):

non sequitur

> 1. An inference or conclusion that does not follow from the premises or evidence.
> 2. A statement that does not follow logically from what preceded it.
>     Latin: nōn sequitur, it does not follow.
>     [American
>      Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/non+sequitur)

Wikipedia uses the term non sequitur as another name for a formal fallacy:

> In philosophy, a formal fallacy, deductive fallacy, logical fallacy or
>   non sequitur (Latin for "it does not follow") is a pattern of
>   reasoning rendered invalid by a flaw in its logical structure...
>   [Formal fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_fallacy)

In your sentence about Socrates, since it doesn't follow logically that you should drink hemlock because Socrates drank it, it logically doesn't follow, and so is a non sequitur.